# XML Schema with a combination of "choice" and "all"

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write an XSD that will validate XML where the following must be true:

An element (Parent) includes:

- either "Choice1" OR "Choice2" elements
- plus any or all of "Field1", "Field2", "Field2" (etc.)
- The above fields can appear in any order

So, for example, valid XML would be:

```
<Parent>
  <Choice1>xxx</Choice1>
  <Field1>yyy</Field1>
  <Field2>yyy</Field2>
</Parent>
```

as would:

```
<Parent>
  <Field3>yyy</Field3>
  <Choice2>xxx</Choice2>
  <Field2>yyy</Field2>
</Parent>
```

Invalid would be:

```
<Parent>
  <Field3>yyy</Field3>
  <Field2>yyy</Field2>
</Parent>
```

I can't seem to nest xs:choice and xs:all as I would like to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `<xs:choice>` cannot be inserted directly in `<xs:all>`.
But you can achieve the same effect using a substitution group:

```
<xs:element name="Parent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element ref="Choice" minOccurs="1"/>

      <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Choice" abstract="true"/>
<xs:element name="Choice1" substitutionGroup="Choice"> ... </xs:element>
<xs:element name="Choice2" substitutionGroup="Choice"> ... </xs:element>
```

Comment: You need to add `minOccurs="0"` to the Field1, Field2 definitions to get what the OP wanted (I think - "any or all of Field1, Field2, etc"... I'm assuming "none" is also valid?)... but very nicely done otherwise.

Comment: @dcsohl You are right, but it was just the knowledge about the substitutionGroup that I was missing, my current schema has appropriate minOccurs etc.